# Differential equation of $y=e^{ax+by}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can you find the differential equation that the function $y=e^{ax+by}$ satisfies. I have tried taking derivative but couldn't obliterate the constant from derived equation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is $x$ ? A function ?

Comment: "The" differential equation?  What makes you think there is uniqueness?

Comment: $y$ is a function of $x$.

Comment: Since there are two constants $a,,b$; there could be a second order ODE  with out containing $a,b$.

Answer (score 1):

One needs two construct a second order ODE by elliminating two constans $a$ and $b$.
$$y=e^{ax+by} \implies \frac{ \log y-by}{x}=a$$
D.w.r.t. $x$, we get
$$\frac{x(y'/y-by')-(\log y-by)}{x^2}=0.$$
$$\implies xy'/y-\log y=b(xy'-y)\implies \frac{xy'/y-\log y}{(xy'-y)}=b$$
D.w.r.t. $x$ again we get aan ODE of second order. We get
$$\frac{(xyy'-y^2)[y'-xy''-y'\log y-yy'/y]-(xy'-y\log y)[-yy'+xy'^2+xy'y'']}{(xy'-y)^2}=0.$$
Finally the required (nonlinear) ODE is
$$(xyy'-y^2)[y'-xy''-y'\log y-yy'/y]-(xy'-y\log y)[-yy'+xy'^2+xy'y'']=0.$$
It may be checked and simplified further.

Comment: Thanks @Z Ahmed

Comment: @math Welcome,you may accept the answer and upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you meant

$$y(x) = e^{ax+by(x)}$$

Since $y>0$, you can take the log:

$$\ln y(x) = ax+by(x)$$

Taking the derivative, you get

$$\frac{y'(x)}{y(x)}  = a + by'(x)$$

Simply multiplying by $y$ on both sides and reorganizing the terms, you get one possible differential equation for $y$:

$$ay+byy'-y'=0$$

Note that you can find as many differential equations for $y$ as you like, since it is not unique.

Comment: The idea is to construct a second order ODE without containing $a,b$.

Comment: Maybe you are right, but it is not clear from the original question.

Comment: I wish that my comment compliments the question.  ODE s are normally created like this. The number of constant in the solution fix the order of ODE.